# Powershell Get ADUser filter

Tags: powershell

I have an object called `$data`. I want to loop through that object to get ADUsers then do some work with that user. The problem I'm having is that the filter is not returning anything. Here is what I have.

```
foreach($object in $data)
{ 


    $ADuser = Get-ADUser -filter * -Properties * -SearchBase "$($object.ouPath)" |
               ? { $_.objectGUID -eq $object.GUID -and $_.employeeNumber -eq $object.personID } |
                Select-Object employeeNumber,
                    SamAccountName,
                    Enabled
    try
    {}
    catch
    {}
}
```

`$data` contains the following information:

```
personID : 9408
firstName : John
lastName : Doe
GUID : dde044a6-b11a-4c23-a4c3-7dfe798a98ce
ouPath : OU=test,DC=my,DC=domain
```

Comment: at what point in your pipeline code do you NOT get the expected results?

Comment: As aside, don't use `-Properties *` if all you want is these properties `employeeNumber`,
`SamAccountName`, and `Enabled`. (the last two and also `ObjectGUID` are returned by default, so you do not even have to ask for them.. P.S. what is the meaning of the empty try..catch in the loop?

Comment: Use the Windows Server ADAC GUI (PowerShell History Viewer) to write the baseline code for you then tweak as needed.  [To construct a script using PowerShell History Viewer](https://www.bing.com/search?q=powershell+history+viewer&form=ANSPH1&refig=2888cb70a59747b1b586099553048f88&sp=-1&pq=powershell+history+viewe&sc=2-24&qs=n&sk=&cvid=2888cb70a59747b1b586099553048f88)

Comment: If I comment out `? { $_.objectGUID -eq $object.GUID -and $_.employeeNumber -eq $object.personID } |` then I get all users in the searchbase. What I need to get is a specific user that has a GUID equal to `$object.GUID` and employeeNumber equal to `$object.personID`. The try/catch is not empty in my code. It's just here for illustration purposes.

Comment: Are you sure you want the `EmployeeNumber` and not the `EmployeeID` user attribute? Can you find the user with using  `-Filter "objectGUID -eq '$($object.GUID)'"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your query without the conditions in the `Where-Object` clause works, then there either is no user with that combination of attributes, OR you are mistaking `EmployeeNumber` with `EmployeeID`.

Also, getting **all** users first with **all** of their properties and filtering out the one user you seek after that is wasteful. Better use the `-Filter` parameter which gets things done way faster.

Something like:

```
foreach($object in $data) { 
    # check if you don't need the EmployeeID attribute instead of EmployeeNumber
    $filter = "ObjectGUID -eq '$($object.GUID)' -and EmployeeNumber -eq '$($object.personID)'"
    $ADuser = Get-ADUser -Filter $filter -Properties EmployeeNumber -SearchBase $object.ouPath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    if ($ADuser) {
        # user found, do what needs to be done here. For demo, just output to console
        $ADuser | Select-Object EmployeeNumber, SamAccountName, Enabled
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "Could not find user with ObjectGUID = '$($object.GUID)' and EmployeeNumber = '$($object.personID)'"
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a million times faster than what I was doing! Also, I found that I wasn't returning the expected user because the user could not be found in the `-searchbase`. I removed the `-searchbase` and everything is awesome now. Thanks